# How to fix problem with manifest.xml and run app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Working with Android Studio 3.2 and i have problem with Running app because of the error "App Default Activity not found" . It is telling me look your manifest.xml because have problem in code for app
Problem -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/301Mu.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erik.firebaseauthdemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ForgetAndChangePasswordActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is another quick trick instead of restart.
Select no activity instead of default activity.

[image: Fix]